# Using ObjectiveC Library in React Native

Tags: javascript, chromecast, react-native

I'm trying to build a Chromecast App with React Native, and my options for the Chromecast library are either an ObjectiveC version.

With React Native, how would I get the ObjectiveC library into my React Native App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The React Native documentation walks you through writing a native module to expose JavaScript functions that can call Objective-C methods: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html.

Answer (score 1):

Chromecast App using React Native (Swift)

https://github.com/holoed/ChromeCast_ReactNative